# Auto-adjust fragment based on screen orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm an Android newbie. I want to change the arrangement of fragments on my screen based on screen orientation. I have created a folder named "layout-land" and created an alternative layout file with a different value for orientation.

However, when I change the orientation of my emulator, nothing changes. What am I doing wrong?

My layout-land xml is as shown below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentTitles"
        android:name="com.src.androidbooks.BookListFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_book_list" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentDescription"
        android:name="com.src.androidbooks.BookDescFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_book_desc" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My layout xml is as shown:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <fragment
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:name="com.src.androidbooks.BookListFragment"
      android:id="@+id/fragmentTitles"
      tools:layout="@layout/fragment_book_list"/>

  <fragment
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:name="com.src.androidbooks.BookDescFragment"
      android:id="@+id/fragmentDescription"
      tools:layout="@layout/fragment_book_desc"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Part of my manifest file looks like this:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.src.androidbooks.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Part of my MainActivity file is shown below:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Log.d("Debug", "CHANGED!");
}
```

I have imported android.content.res.Configuration in my MainActivity file

Comment: What do you mean by change the resolution? The `layout-land` modifier reacts to screen orientation changes, in this case to landscape orientation. You have to actually change the orientation for this to work, not just the resolution.

Comment: @XaverKapeller: Edited my description search for "android:orientation" in both code samples.

Comment: Do you override onConfigurationChanges in your Activity or configChange in your AndroidManifest.xml file? If so, activity is not recreating and it using old layout.

Comment: @Demand: Yes I have, have a look at the code snippets shown